# Cannot drag to edit vertices in ArcGis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, arcgis-10.4, vertices

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nzEikFUt5O8

I am using ArcGis ArcMap 10.4

I have an existing shape that I am trying to edit the vertices of. I open the editing toolbar, and can select the point, but cannot move the point.

What should I be doing?

Comment: Your video seems to show you successfully beginning to Edit Vertices and highlighting them but you seem to be unable to choose a vertex and thus are unable to move it.  Did you start editing vertices by double-clicking the feature or by using another method?  Have you closed and re-opened ArcMap?

Comment: I can select the feature, and get into Edit Vertices, but I cannot select a vertex to drag it. When I drag over a vertex, it becomes red with a white center, but I cannot drag it. I can delete vertices easily with the tool, but I cannot add more vertices to the line.

Comment: I've made a local copy of the DB, and am editing the locally saved copy. Same issue occurs. I have rebooted the computer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PL7pVGbxBo

Comment: Many potential answerers may be unwilling to follow your link to view a video so can you add some screenshots into your question, please?  Normally to move a vertex I just mouse-over it and when it changes I click and drag.  Is this a polygon or a line?  If it is a polygon does it have a neighboring polygon?  Are you using either a geodatabase topology or a map topology or a parcel fabric?

Comment: The problem that I was having was, when mousing over a selected vertex, the cursor would not change to the 'move' mode and I could not drag the drag-edit the vertex to move the position. The issue occurred when the polygon data was hosted on the server, and when the polygon data shape file was copied to the local computer from the server and then edited on the local computer. The issue did not occur in a new MXD, and did not occur when a copy of the broken MXD was created using the 'MXD Doctor' utility and the new copy was edited.

Comment: Cursor not working in old file: http://i.imgur.com/uP6oDhk.png

Cursor working in new file: http://i.imgur.com/488wIvS.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after creating new MXD.

Underlying cause not found.

See [for more details and troubleshooting that I took](https://geonet.esri.com/message/666719-re-cannot-drag-to-edit-vertices)